# How would split up the tail for this cartoon whale in blender?

Tags: modeling, mesh, topology

I am trying to make a potted plant that is in a cartoon-ish whale pot. However, I got to the general whale shape and then couldn't find out how to split up the back part. I used an Iso sphere and then extended out one side for a tail, but I think that because the tail isn't symmetrical it isn't helping. I'm not really sure what to do. I have included pictures of the goal and of what I have now.
[image: what i have]
[image: what i want]

Answer (score 1):

I think you should start with a **cube** or **UV shpere** which have *quads* and *symmetry topology*. Plan the topology before start, then you would know how much geometry to start with. Also, Using **Mirror Modifier** would be handy for modelling symmetry form.

Comment: what do you mean by plan before I start?

Comment: Understand the from. Analysis how the form lines go. Plan how to archive it with the tools and skills you have.

Answer (score 0):

And don't forget that you can subdivide single edges to add vert's to them that you can then connect your own edges to.  worse comes to worse you could just add some extra edges where you need em to divide up the faces in order to make them easier to work with.

Another possible option would be to subdivide the tail a few times then kick over to sculpting and use the crease tool to create the split in the tail.